# Unable to setup bluetooth dongle

Tags: bluetooth

Recently I got Nano USB to Bluetooth Dongle v2.0.

I tried to install it by following [the instructions](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/installing-the-raspberry-pi-nano-bluetooth-dongle) but culdn't figure out why the module is not visible.

I ran the following procedure:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
yudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez-utils blueman
```

but when running lsusb, the device is not visible. Does anyone know what could be wrong or how to fix the issue?

Comment: did you have any chance in resolving your issue? if yes, could you close this question? (by accepting an answer, or adding one, or editing or removing your question)

Answer (score 2):

First check if usb device is recognized at all.
After pluging it in check run

```
sudo dmesg
```

If is not correctly recognized it can be hardware fault or, as it is common with raspberry, not enough power supplied from raspberry. Check it again with powered hub or Linux PC/laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I just had some hardtime with a 4.0 dongle myself. The *lsusb* command wouldn't show my device either despite updating everything.
It was strange as *dmesg* would show it. I ended up taking a new one!
Try out another dongle!